# Flutter - Scroll to Top when onDoubleTap on icon

Tags: flutter, scroll

On Flutter, with the package [persistent_bottom_nav_bar](https://pub.dev/packages/persistent_bottom_nav_bar), how can I Scroll to Top of the screen when `onDoubleTap` on icon please ?

I tried something like this but nothing I tried work.

```
PersistentBottomNavBarItem( icon: GestureDetector( onDoubleTap: () { PrimaryScrollController.of(context).animateTo( 0.0, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500), curve: Curves.decelerate, ); }, child: Icon( Icons.whatshot, color: Colors.black, size: 33.0, ), ), title: "Home", activeColor: Colors.black54, inactiveColor: Colors.grey, ),
```

But have this error :

```
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown while handling a gesture: The method 'animateTo' was called on null. Receiver: null
```

Could you please help?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you can give the scroll controller to your listview(if you are using it)
like this

`final _controller = ScrollController();`

and give it to the listview builder.
when the user press the double click then for going to the top you can do like
`_controller.jumpTo(_controller.position.maxScrollExtent)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full example for your understanding. Please check it.

```
class demo extends StatefulWidget {
  _demoViewState createState() => _demoViewState();
}

class _demoViewState extends State<demo> {
  ScrollController _scrollController;
  bool _isOnTop = true;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _scrollController = ScrollController();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _scrollController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  _scrollToTop() {
    _scrollController.animateTo(_scrollController.position.minScrollExtent,
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1000), curve: Curves.easeIn);
    setState(() => _isOnTop = true);
  }

  _scrollToBottom() {
    _scrollController.animateTo(_scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent,
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1000), curve: Curves.easeOut);
    setState(() => _isOnTop = false);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Generated App',
      home: Scaffold(
          body: ListView(
            controller: _scrollController,
            children: [
              Container(
                height: 200,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
              Container(
                height: 200,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
              Container(
                height: 200,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                color: Colors.blueAccent,
              ),
              Container(
                height: 200,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                color: Colors.yellow,
              ),
              Container(
                height: 200,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                color: Colors.greenAccent,
              ),
            ],
          ),
          floatingActionButton: InkWell(
            onDoubleTap: _isOnTop ? _scrollToBottom : _scrollToTop,
            child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.black12,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50)),
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Icon(
                      _isOnTop ? Icons.arrow_downward : Icons.arrow_upward),
                )),
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your replies & help.
Your solutions do work one there own but unfortunately don't fit with my issue as it is regarding the persistent_bottom_nav_bar package.

You will see below the answer received from the package creator :

> This is a custom functionality. It might be added in a future update but as of now, you can only achieve this by using a custom widget. See the bottom part of the Readme for more information on how to use custom widget and what are its limitations.